# Can I pull two tethered objects together?

Tags: just-cause-2

Can I pull tethered objects together like in Just Cause 3?

I literally tried every single button on my keyboard, but can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2):

No, the ability to pull two tethered objects together was a new feature in Just Cause 3 and is not present in Just Cause 2. From the [Protec Grappler G3 wikia page](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Protec_Grappler_G3)'s entry about Just Cause 3:

> It's now possible to retract the cable between two objects that are grappled together.

This indicates that it was not possible prior to this.

Answer (score 0):

The feature to pull an object via holding a button did not exist in Just Cause 2.  Just Cause 3 added it.

You can however [tether two objects together](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/25909/163757).  This isn't quite the same, but its about as close as you can get to what you want to do.